# Apply function row wise on pandas data frame on columns with numerical values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : ['w','x','y','z'], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]:
  AAA  BBB  CCC
0   w   10  100
1   x   20   50
2   y   30  -30
3   z   40  -50
```

What I want to do is to perform function operation on every row for every column except those with non-numerical value (in this case `AAA`). In the real case the non-numerical case is always on first column, and the rest (could be greater than 2 columns) are always numerical.

The final desired output is:

```
  AAA  BBB  CCC  Score
0   w   10  100  110
1   x   20   50   70
2   y   30  -30    0
3   z   40  -50  -10
```

I tried this but failed:

```
import numpy as np
df["Score"] = df.apply(np.sum, axis=1)
```

What's the right way to do it?

**Update2:**

This is the code that give `SettingWithCopyWarning`.
Please fresh start the ipython for testing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
def cvscore(fclist):
    sd = np.std(fclist)
    mean = np.mean(fclist)
    cv = sd/mean
    return cv

def calc_cvscore_on_df(df):
    df["CV"] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(cvscore, axis=1)
    return df

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
calc_cvscore_on_df(df3[["a","b"]])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To select everything but the first column, you could use `df.iloc[:, 1:]`:

```
In [371]: df['Score'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)

In [372]: df
Out[372]: 
  AAA  BBB  CCC  Score
0   w   10  100    110
1   x   20   50     70
2   y   30  -30      0
3   z   40  -50    -10
```

To apply an arbitrary function, `func`, to each row:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(func, axis=1)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def cvscore(fclist):
    sd = np.std(fclist)
    mean = np.mean(fclist)
    cv = sd/mean
    return cv

df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : ['w','x','y','z'], 'BBB' : [10,20,30,40],
                   'CCC' : [100,50,-30,-50]})

df['Score'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(cvscore, axis=1)
print(df)
```

yields

```
  AAA  BBB  CCC     Score
0   w   10  100  1.211386
1   x   20   50  0.868377
2   y   30  -30       NaN
3   z   40  -50 -5.809058
```

Comment: Grumble.  Do you know a better way to handle the general case (where we don't necessarily know which columns are numeric beforehand) than `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: @unutbu: How can I generalize that for generic function. In reality it's not `np.sum` but my other specific function. See update.

Comment: @DSM: `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).sum(axis=1)` seems like a superior answer. What don't you like about it?

Comment: @unutbu: Using your last function I got this warning `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`. How can I resolve that?

Comment: @unutbu: I'm not sure I knew about `np.number` until five minutes ago, and I don't like the restriction to numpy's object space.  What I was sort of hoping for was a version of `astype` which gave `nan` or 0 on fail instead of doing nothing or raising.  Not that important in the grand scheme.

Comment: @unutbu: How can I achive that with `.loc` version to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`?

Comment: @pdubois: Could you post the code you are using? I'm not seeing any `SettingWithCopyWarning` when using `df['Score'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(cvscore, axis=1)`.

Comment: @unutbu: The data is too large to put it here.

Comment: @pdubois: The real data is unnecessary if you can prepare a minimal example which reproduces the warning. Or, start by posting the line of code which raises the warning. Are you using [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-the-assignment-when-using-chained-indexing-fail)?

Comment: @pdubois: The warning is saying that `df3[['a','b']]['CV'] = ...` will fail to
modify `df3`. Since `calc_cvscore_on_df` returns a new `df`, it appears you aren't trying to modify `df3`. So the easiest way to avoid the warning is to put 
`df = df.copy()` at the beginning of `calc_cvscore_on_df`. Then `df` will be its own independent DataFrame, and `df['CV'] = ...` will not raise the warning.

Comment: @unutbu, I got error by divide by 0, I don't get NaN like your result?

Comment: @BIN I got that error too. I guess that's from only Python 3. I add `try` and `except` pair to `cvscore` and now it works.